# Lightbox alignment issue

Tags: css-float, alignment, lightbox

on button click i m opening lightbox. I am displaying content on it. Lightbox working fine. In High Resolution alignment of the lightbox is center to the screen. If i see the same in normal resolution 1024 *768. Lightbox showing in left of the screen. I want to show it in center of the screen it any resolutions.
 I am using following css.

```
.white_content_note {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        padding: 15px 25px;
        opacity:1.00;
        border: 2px solid #c90000;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        z-index:1002;
        border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        top:165px;
        margin:0;
        font-family:Calibri;
        right:455px;
        behavior:url(images/PIE.htc);   
    }
```

Even i try position : relative;
margin: 50px auto;

It not working. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should use a relative setting for your right alignment:
    right:455px;

and change the position to relative also.

Comment: Can you give some more context, for instance your html or a jsfiddle so I can take a look?

Comment: <div class="white_content_note" id="div_viewData">

/* Here i am displaying some content */

</div>

Comment: One line of html does not count as context.